# Change numeric values in one column based on factor levels in another column

Tags: r, if-statement, dataframe

I need to set certain numeric values in one column of my data frame to zero, if in another column they have a certain factor level.

My dataframe df looks something like:

```
Items Store.Type
5      A
4      B
3      C
6      D
3      B
7      E
```

What I want to do is make Items = 0, for all rows where Store.Type = "A" or "C"

I'm very new to R, but figured this this would be a conditional statement of the form "If Store.Type A then Items <- 0" (and then repeat for Store.Type C), but I didn't understand the `?"if"` page at all. I tried:

```
df$ItemsFIXED <- with(df, if(Store.Type == "A")Items <-0)
```

and got the warning message:

```
Warning message:
In if (Store.Type2 == "Chain - Brand") Total.generic.items <- 0 :
 the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used`
```

So I noticed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11865195/using-if-else-on-a-data-frame), the following:

> - `if` is a control flow statement, taking a single logical value as an argument
> - `ifelse` is a vectorised function, taking vectors as all its arguments.

So figuring I need `ifelse` to do the whole column and being able to understand the `?ifelse` page, I tried to do "If Store.Type A then Items <- 0 else do nothing". In fact I wanted it nested, so I tried the following code (creating a new column for now so I don't mess up my data, but eventually it will overwrite the Items data)

```
df$ItemsFIXED <- with(df, ifelse(Store.Type == "A", Items <-0, 
                          ifelse(Store.Type == "C", Items <-0,)))
```

and got the following error:

```
Error in ifelse(Store.Type2 == "Franchise - Brand", Total.generic.items <- 0,  : 
  argument "no" is missing, with no default
```

But if I put anything in for `no` it simply writes over the values which are correct. I tried putting `Items` and `Items <- Items` in to say "else leave Items as Items" as in the following, but this just changed everything to zero.

```
df$ItemsFIXED <- with(df, ifelse(Store.Type == "A", Items <-0, 
                          ifelse(Store.Type == "C", Items <-0,Items)))
```

Is there a way to tell `ifelse` to do nothing, or is there an easier way to do this?

Comment: `df$Items[which(df$Store.Type == "A" | df$Store.Type == "C" )] <- 0`

Comment: i.e. find the rows that need to be changed, then set those entries to 0.

Comment: Thanks everyone for those solutions, they do indeed all work, but I'm not exactly sure how/why yet! I think the `which` and `%in%` seem to be the simplest ones that I should look into more.

Comment: Oh and @Alex I would vote for your answer but I don't know how, given that it is in a comment...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Or you could use `%in%` for multiple match/replacement

```
 df$Items[df$Store.Type %in% c("A", "C")] <- 0
  df
  #Items Store.Type
  #1     0          A
  #2     4          B
  #3     0          C
  #4     6          D
  #5     3          B
  #6     7          E
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `within` seems to be also an option:

```
within(d, Items[Store.Type %in% c("A","C")]<-0)

  Items Store.Type
1     0          A
2     4          B
3     0          C
4     6          D
5     3          B
6     7          E
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use vectorized replacement here.  If `df` is your data set,

```
> df$Items[with(df, Store.Type == "A" | Store.Type == "C")] <- 0L
> df
#   Items Store.Type
# 1     0          A
# 2     4          B
# 3     0          C
# 4     6          D
# 5     3          B
# 6     7          E
```

`with(df, Store.Type == "A" | Store.Type == "C")` returns a logical vector.  When a logical vector is placed inside `[...]`, only the `TRUE` values are returned.  So if we subset `Items` with those values, we can replace them with `[<-`

Also, if you wanted to use `ifelse`, you could do things like

```
df$Items <- with(df, ifelse(Store.Type == "A" | Store.Type == "C", 0L, Items))
```

or

```
within(df, Items <- ifelse(Store.Type == "A" | Store.Type == "C", 0L, Items))
```

but take note that `ifelse` can be very slow at times, even more so when coupled with `within`, and will likely always be slower than the vectorized method up top.

Answer (score 1):

Following also works:

```
> ddf[ddf$Store.Type=='A'| ddf$Store.Type=='C',]$Items = 0
> ddf
  Items Store.Type
1     0          A
2     4          B
3     0          C
4     6          D
5     3          B
6     7          E
```

Answer (score 0):

it is the best way to solve

> df$Items[which(df$store.type==c('A','C'))]==0

```
 Items Store.Type

1     0          A


2     4          B

3     0          C

4     6          D

5     3          B

6     7          E
```