# How to run a set of conditions on a whole vector

Tags: r

So i have a set of numbers generated using probabilities, and I need to create a data frame that gives a value of X and Y based on what each number in the vector is. The output I need is a data frame with columns of X and Y

Comment: Maybe this post will be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11865195/using-if-else-on-a-data-frame. Please, provide a reproducible example code to make your question more straightforward.

Comment: Welcome to [so]! Please read [ask] and give a [mre] in your question!