# Using an If function, how do I change string of text in dataframe to another string?

Tags: r, dataframe, if-statement

using the following dataset

```
 structure(list(...1 = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 
1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 
9, 10, 11, 12), V1 = c("overstress", "flicker", "lotteri", "life", 
"charg", "capac", "health", "drain", "degrad", "protector", "bright", 
"use", "overstress", "flicker", "lotteri", "life", "charg", "capac", 
"health", "drain", "degrad", "protector", "bright", "use", "overstress", 
"flicker", "lotteri", "life", "charg", "capac", "health", "drain", 
"degrad", "protector", "bright", "use"), term = c("corr1", "corr1", 
"corr1", "corr1", "corr1", "corr1", "corr1", "corr1", "corr1", 
"corr1", "corr1", "corr1", "corr2", "corr2", "corr2", "corr2", 
"corr2", "corr2", "corr2", "corr2", "corr2", "corr2", "corr2", 
"corr2", "corr3", "corr3", "corr3", "corr3", "corr3", "corr3", 
"corr3", "corr3", "corr3", "corr3", "corr3", "corr3"), correlation = c(0.5, 
0.43, 0.42, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0.53, 
0.29, 0.25, 0.25, 0.23, 0.2, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, 0.45, 0.16, 0.15)), row.names = c(NA, -36L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

I am looking to change if the word is corr1, corr2 or corr3, to toil1,toil2 or toil3. I tried the following code, but only receive the following error term:

```
three_terms_corrs_gathered$term <- if
(three_terms_corrs_gathered$term  == "corr1"){toil1} else if
(three_terms_corrs_gathered$term  == "corr2"){toil2} else
{toil3}
```

Warning message:

> In if (three_terms_corrs_gathered$term == "corr1") { :   the condition
> has length > 1 and only the first element will be used.  So it only
> changes to the first condition. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/11865195/3358272

Comment: If so, I don't understand how to generalize it. In the link, they only have two variables and can therefore use ifelse. In my case, I have three conditions. How do I generalize it?

Comment: Options: (1) nested `ifelse`, not my preferred; or (2) `merge` a frame such as `data.frame(term=c("corr1","corr2"),newterm=c(toil1,toil2))`. This second option can be done using `base::merge` or the tidyverse `dplyr::left_join` if you're using that (it appears you are). Three options if you want to consider `dplyr::case_when`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Three options:

1. "Merge" mentality. This works very well when you have multiple disparate matches, as it is both efficient for code *and* easy to visualize and maintain. While the example here only has two replacements, the code doesn't change if `corrs_df` has 2 rows or 200, and entries in `corrs_df` that match nothing are silently discarded, doing no harm.

   ```r
   library(dplyr)
   corrs_df <- data.frame(term = c("corr1", "corr2"), newterm = c("toil1", "toil2"))
   dat %>%
     left_join(corrs_df, by = "term") %>%
     slice(c(1:3, 28:30))
   # # A tibble: 6 x 5
   #    ...1 V1         term  correlation newterm
   #   <dbl> <chr>      <chr>       <dbl> <chr>  
   # 1     1 overstress corr1        0.5  toil1  
   # 2     2 flicker    corr1        0.43 toil1  
   # 3     3 lotteri    corr1        0.42 toil1  
   # 4     4 life       corr3       NA    <NA>   
   # 5     5 charg      corr3       NA    <NA>   
   # 6     6 capac      corr3       NA    <NA>   

   dat %>%
     left_join(corrs_df, by = "term") %>%
     mutate(term = coalesce(newterm, term)) %>%
     slice(c(1:3, 28:30))
   # # A tibble: 6 x 5
   #    ...1 V1         term  correlation newterm
   #   <dbl> <chr>      <chr>       <dbl> <chr>  
   # 1     1 overstress toil1        0.5  toil1  
   # 2     2 flicker    toil1        0.43 toil1  
   # 3     3 lotteri    toil1        0.42 toil1  
   # 4     4 life       corr3       NA    <NA>   
   # 5     5 charg      corr3       NA    <NA>   
   # 6     6 capac      corr3       NA    <NA>
   ```

   You can obviously `%>% select(-newterm)`.) The `coalesce` function effectively says *"give me the first non-NA value from these variables"*. The `NA` in newterm occurs when the associated `term` variable is not present in `corrs_df`, which we assume means to make no change.
2. `dplyr::case_when`. (If you're into it, then `data.table::fcase` does effectively the same thing.)

   ```r
   dat %>%
     mutate(
       term = case_when(
         term == "corr1" ~ "toil1",
         term == "corr2" ~ "toil2",
         TRUE ~ term)
     ) %>%
     slice(c(1:3, 28:30))
   # # A tibble: 6 x 4
   #    ...1 V1         term  correlation
   #   <dbl> <chr>      <chr>       <dbl>
   # 1     1 overstress toil1        0.5 
   # 2     2 flicker    toil1        0.43
   # 3     3 lotteri    toil1        0.42
   # 4     4 life       corr3       NA   
   # 5     5 charg      corr3       NA   
   # 6     6 capac      corr3       NA
   ```
3. Nested `ifelse`. Actually, since you're using `dplyr`, it is *much* better to use `if_else` for many reasons (e.g., [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6668963/3358272)).

   ```r
   dat %>%
     mutate(
       term = if_else(term == "corr1", "toil1",
                      if_else(term == "corr2", "toil2", term))
     ) %>%
     slice(c(1:3, 28:30))
   # # A tibble: 6 x 4
   #    ...1 V1         term  correlation
   #   <dbl> <chr>      <chr>       <dbl>
   # 1     1 overstress toil1        0.5 
   # 2     2 flicker    toil1        0.43
   # 3     3 lotteri    toil1        0.42
   # 4     4 life       corr3       NA   
   # 5     5 charg      corr3       NA   
   # 6     6 capac      corr3       NA
   ```

   This works fine for 1 or 2 nestings, but in my *opinion*, it looks messy and it gets difficult to follow; in my *experience*, because it is harder to follow, it can be harder to maintain, making it quite simple to have incorrect placement of particular options/values. Maintainability and readability are very important in my opinion.

Comment: Thank you so much. Worked perfectly. Saved my evening.