# Want to determine where column value is greater than 20 or less than -20 and filter to those rows R

Tags: r, dataframe, filter

I have a data frame as follows

```
id <- c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
week1 <- c(-20.1, 15, 40, -15, 3.43)
week2 <- c(-10.1, 35, 67, -32, 33)
week3 <- c(5.1, 45, 2.36, 27, 4)
data <- data.frame(id, week1, week2, week3)
```

I would like to find the values in the columns 2 to 4 where the values are either greater than 20 or less than -20 and fill the other values with NA or 0 so that the output would contain those specific values as well as the column containing the id.
Something like:

```
data.frame("id" = c(1,2,3,4,5), 
"week1" = c(-20.1, NA, 40, NA, NA), 
"week2" = c(NA, -35, 67, -32, 33), 
"week3" = c(NA, 45, NA, 27, NA))
```

Any help is great, thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using If/Else on a data frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11865195/using-if-else-on-a-data-frame)

Answer (score 2):

Create a logical on the `abs`olute values of subset and assign to `NA`

```
data[2:4][abs(data[2:4]) <= 20] <- NA
```

-output

```
data
  id week1 week2 week3
1  1 -20.1    NA    NA
2  2    NA    35    45
3  3  40.0    67    NA
4  4    NA   -32    27
5  5    NA    33    NA
```

Comment: Thank you! Is there a way to do so that I could obtain values either >20 or <-20 rather than also getting values in between (-20, 20) since I would be using "<="

Comment: @JaneMiller I was thinking of a concise option, but you can always create condition as `data[2:4][data[2:4] > 20|data[2:4] < -20] <- NA`